Jordan curve theorem for a connected open subset of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$?
The generalized Jordan curve or Jordan–Brouwer separation theorem operates on the whole Euclidean space. Is there a similar proposition such as the following operating on a connected open subset? Is it an easy corollary of the former? How would one prove it?
Let $X$ be a topological sphere in an open connected subset $U$ of the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^{n+1}, n\in\mathbb N$, i.e., the image of an injective continuous mapping of the $n$-sphere $S^n$ into $U$. Then the complement $U-X$ consists of exactly two connected components, $X$ is their common boundary.

Yes and it does not have to be a sphere, any compact connected hypersurface will work as well.

@MoisheKohan: Could you please provide the proof? It would be particularly nice if you could constructed it as a corollary of the Jordan curve theorem.

The Jordan curve theorem is a result for $n=1$.

@PaulFrost: I am referring to the generalized version. See my edited first sentence of my question.

@Hans Everybody here is volunteering their spare time; making the same request twice starts to seem pushy.
